# Response to ‘Where’s your luggage?’

Tags: grammar, determiners

> -- Where’s your luggage? 
> -- I haven’t got __________
>  A. One
>  B. Some
>  C. **Any**

I thought the answers were A and C both, but it’s C. Why not A?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/luggage), **luggage** is uncountable... this is indicated by the **[U]** next to the definition. Countable nouns have **[C]** or **[plural]** next to the definition.

Other uncountable nouns include water and sugar, and abstract concepts like peace. Uncountable nouns are treated as singular for verb agreement, but plural for most other things, for example determiners. Here is a verb example:

> My luggage **is** in the car

For countable nouns, you use the determiner **one** for singlar positive and negative statements, **some** for plural positive statements, and **any** for plural negative statements.

Uncountable nouns require plural determiners, so you can't use **one**- you have have to use **some** or **any**. Your statement is negative, so you say

> Where’s your luggage?
> I haven’t got **any**

Answer (score 1):

Luggage = all the cases, bags and items that you have with you on your journey

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/luggage)

It is therefore a plural. You cannot have one luggage. You might have *one suitcase*, but you have *some luggage*.

Comment: Luggage is not plural: it is uncountable.